How did Ramanujan find $\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(1/2)_n(1/4)_n(3/4)_n}{n!^3}\frac{644n+41}{25920^n}=\frac{288\sqrt{5}}{5\pi}?$
The formula
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty (-1)^n\frac{(1/2)_n(1/4)_n(3/4)_n}{n!^3}\frac{644n+41}{25920^n}=\frac{288\sqrt{5}}{5\pi}$$
(in older notation) appears as eq. 38 in Ramanujan's paper Modular equations and approximations to $\pi$; $(a)_n$ is the Pochhammer symbol.
But – the formula is like an exercise for the reader. Allegedly, it can be deduced from the theory of modular equations, but how exactly?
It should be somehow possible to prove the formula from Clausen's formulas and representations of
$$25P(q^{50})-P(q^2)$$
where
$$P(q)=1-24\sum_{k=1}^\infty \frac{kq^k}{1-q^k}$$
with $|q|\lt 1$. The hypergeometric representation of Ramanujan's formula is known to be
$$41\,_3F_2\left(\frac14,\frac12,\frac34,1,1,-\frac{1}{25920}\right)-\frac{161}{69120}\,  _3F_2\left(\frac54,\frac32,\frac74,2,2,-\frac{1}{25920}\right)=\frac{288\sqrt{5}}{5\pi}.$$
What I tried
Let
$$K(x)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\dfrac{dt}{\sqrt{1-x\sin^2 t}}$$
and
$$E(x)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-x\sin^2 t}\,dt$$
be the elliptic integrals.
Using the hypergeometric differential equation, the problem at hand shoud then be reducible to
$$K\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-6\sqrt{-360+161\sqrt{5}}\right)\left(2E\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-6\sqrt{-360+161\sqrt{5}}\right)-\left(1+\sqrt{-840+376\sqrt{5}}\right)K\left(\dfrac{1}{2}-6\sqrt{-360+161\sqrt{5}}\right)\right)=\frac{\pi}{10}.$$
Now I recognized the argument of the elliptic integrals as a special value of the modular lambda function $\lambda$ (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_lambda_function):
$$\lambda (5i)=\dfrac{1}{2}-6\sqrt{-360+161\sqrt{5}}.$$
So if someone can prove that
$$K(\lambda (5i))=\dfrac{\sqrt{5}+2}{20}\dfrac{\Gamma (1/4)^2}{\sqrt{\pi}}$$
and
$$E(\lambda (5i))=\dfrac{(-2+\sqrt{5})\pi^{3/2}}{\Gamma (1/4)^2}+\dfrac{\left(2+\sqrt{5}+2\sqrt{-10+6\sqrt{5}}\right)\Gamma (1/4)^2}{40\sqrt{\pi}},$$
(that's out of my reach), then Ramanujan's formula is proved.
Edit
I noticed that $K(\lambda (5i))$ can be easily proved to have the desired closed form by using division values of elliptic functions with parameter $-1$. But evaluating $E(\lambda (5i))$ seems hard...
Edit #2
The question has been answered on MathOverflow:
https://mathoverflow.net/questions/469126/how-did-ramanujan-find-sum-n-0-infty-1n-frac1-2-n1-4-n3-4-nn/469135#469135

crossposted at https://mathoverflow.net/q/469126/11260

Ramanujan's paper contains the technique to derive such series based on a given hypergeometric type series for $(2K/\pi)^2$ and he illustrates the technique with a simple example. The series in question requires a different series for $(2K/\pi)^2$ and is given in my answer.

The series in question needs modular equation of degree $25=5^2$ which can be reduced to modular equation of degree $5$ and the calculations can be done by hand. Ramanujan gave another series involving a modular equation of degree $37$ and so far no one has done the corresponding calculations by hand. The resulting series however is extremely beautiful with no square roots in it $$\frac{4}{\pi}=\frac{1123}{882}-\frac{22583}{882^{3}}\cdot\frac{1}{2}\cdot\frac{1\cdot 3}{4^{2}}+\frac{44043}{882^{5}}\cdot\frac{1\cdot 3}{2\cdot 4}\cdot\frac{1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot 7}{4^{2}\cdot 8^{2}}-\dots$$

@ParamanandSingh Nomas2 . Ramanujan notes that if $k_{n^2}$ for n=2,3,4,... all depends on $k_{1}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$. "We can use the same table to find the sum of (19) ...". This makes me think that Ramanujan was not interested in evaluate $K(k_{n^2})$ but was aware that all values where the same essentially depending of $\Gamma(1/4)$ and algebraic numbers.

@User: yes Ramanujan was aware of those things and he says that the value of $f(n) = nP(q^{2n})-P(q^2)$ for $n=rs$ can be obtained using values $f(r), f(s) $. When $r=s$ so that $n=r^2$ then the calculations are simpler and depend only on one modular equation of degree $r$ instead of a modular equation of degree $r$ and another modular equation of degree $s$.

@ParamanandSingh Do you think that write the modular equations given by Ramanujan in terms of theta functions could be an interesting translation?

Let us use the more standard notation with $k\in(0,1)$ being elliptic modulus and $k'=\sqrt{1-k^2}$ being the complementary modulus. The elliptic integrals are defined by $$K(k) =\int_0^{\pi/2}\frac {dx} {\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}},E(k)=\int_0^{\pi/2}\sqrt{1-k^2\sin^2x}\,dx\tag{1}$$ The integrals $K(k), K(k'), E(k), E(k') $ are often denoted by $K, K', E, E'$ when the values $k, k'$ are available from context.
Let us now bring other players into this game and we write $q=\exp(-\pi K'/K) $ and call it the nome corresponding to modulus $k$. Ramanujan now makes use of the Dedekind eta function $$\eta(q) =q^{1/24}\prod_{n\geq 1}(1-q^n)\tag{2}$$ and its logarithmic derivative $$P(q) = 24q\frac{d}{dq}\log\eta(q)=1-24\sum_{n\geq 1}\frac{nq^n}{1-q^n}\tag{3}$$ We have the identity $$\eta(q^2)=2^{-1/3}\sqrt{\frac{2K}{\pi}}(kk')^{1/6}\tag{4}$$ which will be used in combination with the hypergeometric identity $$ \left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right)^{2} = (1 - 2k^{2})^{-1}\,_{3}F_{2}\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2}; 1, 1; -\left(\frac{G^{12} - G^{-12}}{2}\right)^{-2}\right)\tag{5}$$ where $G=G(k) =(2kk') ^{-1/12}$ is one of Ramanujan's class invariant. Using these identities we get $$\eta^4(q^2)=\frac{2^{-4/3}(kk')^{2/3}}{1-2k^2} \,_{3}F_{2}\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2}; 1, 1; -\left(\frac{G^{12} - G^{-12}}{2}\right)^{-2}\right)\tag{6}$$ Next formidable step is to logarithmically differentiate the above identity with respect to $k$ to get a formula for $P(q^2)$. The calculations can be verified  with hand and some patience and we write a few steps here. First we note that $$\frac{dK} {dk} =\frac{E-k'^2K}{kk'^2}$$ and then using the Legendre's identity $$KE'+K'E-KK'=\frac{\pi} {2}$$ we can obtain the derivative $$\frac{dq} {dk} =\frac{\pi^2q}{2kk'^2K^2}$$ Next we have $$P(q^2)=3q\frac{d}{dq}\log\eta^4(q^2)=\frac{3kk'^2}{2}\left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right)^2\frac{d}{dk}\log\eta^4(q^2)$$ which further leads us to $$P(q^2)=\frac{3kk'^2}{2}\left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right)^2\frac{d}{dk}\left(\log (2^{-4/3}(kk')^{2/3})+\log\left(\frac {2K}{\pi}\right) ^2\right) $$ Then we get $$P(q^2)=\left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right) ^2(1-2k^2)+\frac{3kk'^2}{2}\frac{d}{dk}\left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right)^2$$ Using $(5)$ we now get $$P(q^2)=\left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right) ^2\cdot\frac{1+2k^2k'^2}{1-2k^2}+\frac{3kk'^2}{2(1-2k^2)}\frac{d}{dk}\,_{3}F_{2}\left(\frac{1}{4},\frac{3}{4},\frac{1}{2}; 1, 1; -\left(\frac{G^{12} - G^{-12}}{2}\right)^{-2}\right)$$ Switching to sigma notation we get $$P(q^2)=\frac{1+2k^2k'^2}{(1-2k^2)^2}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{(1/4)_n(1/2)_n(3/4)_n}{(n!)^3}\cdot\left(\frac{G^{12} - G^{-12}}{2}\right)^{-2n}+\frac{3kk'^2}{2(1-2k^2)}\cdot\frac{f'(k)}{f(k)}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{n(1/4)_n(1/2)_n(3/4)_n}{(n!)^3}\left(\frac{G^{12} - G^{-12}}{2}\right)^{-2n}$$ where $$f(k)= \left(\frac{G^{12} - G^{-12}}{2}\right)^{-2}$$ We have $$\frac{f'(k)} {f(k)} =(\log f(k)) '=\frac{2(1-2k^2)}{kk'^2}\cdot\frac{G^{12}+G^{-12}}{G^{12}-G^{-12}}$$ Thus we finally obtain $$P(q^2)=\frac{1+2k^2k'^2}{(1-2k^2)^2}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{(1/4)_n(1/2)_n(3/4)_n}{(n!)^3}\cdot\left(\frac{G^{12} - G^{-12}}{2}\right)^{-2n}+\frac{3(G^{12}+G^{-12})}{G^{12}-G^{-12}}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{n(1/4)_n(1/2)_n(3/4)_n}{(n!)^3}\left(\frac{G^{12} - G^{-12}}{2}\right)^{-2n}\tag{7} $$ Next we put $q=e^{-5\pi}$ in above relation and corresponding values $$2k^2=1-\sqrt{1-\phi^{-24}},2k'^2=1+\sqrt{1-\phi^{-24}}, G=(4k^2k'^2)^{-1/24}=\phi$$ (where $\phi=(1+\sqrt{5})/2$ is golden ratio) and observe that $$G^{12}-G^{-12}=F_{12}\phi+F_{11}-(-F_{12}\phi+F_{13})=2F_{12}\phi-F_{12}=F_{12}\sqrt{5}=144\sqrt{5}$$ (where $F_n$ is the Fibonacci sequence) and $$G^{12}+G^{-12}=F_{11}+F_{13}=322$$ and $$\frac{1+2k^2k'^2}{(1-2k^2)^2}=\frac{2F_{24}\phi+2F_{23}+1}{2F_{24}\phi+2F_{23}-2}=\frac{30912\phi+19105}{30912\phi+19104}$$ The above ratio can be simplified (using technique in this answer) to $$\frac{120+161\sqrt{5}}{480}$$ Thus the equation $(7)$ can be rewritten as $$P(q^2)=\frac{120+161\sqrt{5}}{480}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{(1/4)_n(1/2)_n(3/4)_n}{(n!)^3}\cdot\frac{1}{25920^n}+\frac{644\sqrt{5}}{480}\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{n(1/4)_n(1/2)_n(3/4)_n}{(n!)^3}\cdot\frac{1}{25920^n}\tag{8}$$ From equation $(15)$ of this answer dealing with modular equations and related identities we have $$P(q^{2})=\frac{3}{5\pi}+\left(\frac{2K}{\pi}\right) ^26(5-3\phi)\sqrt{3\phi-4}$$ or $$ P(q^{2})=\frac{3}{5\pi}+\frac{6(5-3\phi)\sqrt{3\phi-4}} {\sqrt{1-\phi^{-24}}} \sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^n\cdot\frac{(1/4)_n(1/2)_n(3/4)_n}{(n!)^3}\cdot\frac{1}{25920^n}$$ and this simplifies to $$P(q^{2})=\frac{3}{5\pi}+\frac{120+120\sqrt{5}} {480} \sum_{n\geq 0} (-1)^n\cdot\frac{(1/4)_n(1/2)_n(3/4)_n}{(n!)^3}\cdot\frac{1}{25920^n}\tag{9}$$ Comparing equations $(8),(9)$ we get $$\frac{288\sqrt{5}}{5\pi}=\sum_{n\geq 0}(-1)^n\cdot\frac{(1/4)_n(1/2)_n(3/4)_n}{(n!)^3}\cdot\frac{41+644n}{25920^n} $$

$\displaystyle +1$. That was a lot of work. It was pretty fine.

+1 for sure I'm convinced that the cases $n=37,58,163$ will be discovered to prove by hand.

@User: I am eagerly waiting for the day when someone comes up with those calculations. And I hope it comes from some user on mathse.
